# How do I rename image in OpenStack using command line?

Tags: openstack

I have an image named `old-image-name` in OpenStack.
I want to rename it (say to `new-image-name`).

I know I can do it using "Edit Image" in the web interface. But how can I do it from command line/script?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Done with the `image set` sub-command:

`openstack image set --name new-image-name old-image-name`